# Best fit of a couple of points to a data set.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I have a mathematical problem that I will be explaining below. Hope I can get some advice on the best way to calculate a solution.

Problem:
I have 4 values:
$x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ and $x_4$ with $x_2 = 3x_1$ and $x_4 = 3x_3$

I also have a data set of n values. I need find $x_1$ and $x_3$ so that my 4 values best fits into the data set.

Example 1: If I had a 4 value data set with the values 2, 3, 6 and 9, the best fit would be $x_1 = 2$ and $x_3 = 3$, which would then fit the data perfectly ($x_1 = 2$, $x_2 = 6$, $x_3 = 3$ and $x_4 = 9$. However my data set could have any number of values and usually won't have a perfect fit, so I need a formula that I can use to find the optimal $x_1$ and $x_3$.

Example 2: If I I'm only using $x_1$ and $x_2$ and I have a data set of 2 points 2 and 7, then the best fit I'd be looking for would be $x_1 = 2.25$ since that puts $x_1$ only 0.25 away from 2 and $x_2 = 6.75$ which is 0.25 away from 7.

Any ideas?

Edit:
The background to this problem is that I have several presses that are actuated by pressure from one of two pressure manifolds. I calculate the pressures required in each press (my data set), and I can then select which manifold (low pressure or high pressure, $x_2$ and $x_4$) to link them too, and I can also set them to only use a 3rd of the pressure ($x_1$ and $x_3$). I need to figure out what the optimal low and high pressures should be to fit the pressures in each press as closely as possible to the pressures I require from them. Hope that clarifies the problem a bit.

Comment: How are you defining "best fit" in your setup?

Comment: I'm not actually quite sure myself, hence the example. I'll add a bit of background to the question that will hopefully clarify.

Comment: But that example had four points, and you just chose the same values

Comment: Yea, maybe add some context to the problem

Comment: Yea, I chose those points so I can check the formula when I can figure it out. If the formula is correct, I should get x1 and x2 as 2 and 3 respectively (or vice versa) for that specific data set.